# Word2013 interop not open password file having length > 15 in C#

Tags: office-interop

i am using Word interop in C# application.

using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

var app = new Word.Application(); 
var doc = app.Documents.Open("file.docx", PasswordDocument: ""); 
I am trying to open word file having password length > 15. It gives error of invalid command line.

Same file can open by giving manual password in document file.

Any solution from coding side for this issue?